# Configuring Wordpress on Google Cloud (Google Click to Deploy)

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to set up a wordpress site on Google Cloud. I just installed it, hardware selection etc. I didn't do any other configuration etc.

I am facing the following problem on wordpress.jinja:

`This deployment has resources from the Runtime Configurator service, which is in Beta. There is no planned date for moving this feature into General Availability (GA). Examples of runtimeconfig types used: runtimeconfig.v1beta1.config, runtimeconfig.v1beta1.waiter`

According to this, i can't login phpMyAdmin as well. There are lots of error and can't view tables.

What should I do about these problem?

[On Google Cloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjnNs.png)

Comment: Ask on https://serverfault.com/  as people there may have answers.

Answer (score -1):

As the warning message states that the feature that you would like to use is not completely available yet and there is no planned date as well and to confirm this I have tried creating the same deployment in my test environment and I even ended up with the same warning message even after it was deployed.

The warning was an intended behavior and made to notify that the product you are trying to use [Run time Configurator](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/runtime-configurator) is still at Pre-GA offerings hence not to rely completely on it. If you want to continue the usage of the respective deployments using Run time Configurator you can ignore the default warning messages.

I am able to login on my phpMyAdmin console where deprecation warning messages are present also, the same from your screenshot.

Currently, Click to Deploy uses phpMyAdmin 5.02 and php 8.1. Deprecation warning messages are [fixed on phpMyAdmin 5.1](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16268)

You may [file a feature request](https://%20https://issuetracker.google.com) for the phpMyAdmin to be upgraded to a newer version. However, there is no guaranteed ETA for it.